# Why is AccessCheck NOT applying GenericMapping to the DACL?

Tags: winapi, permissions, dacl

The AccessCheck function gets a GenericMapping parameter. What is this parameter used for? It is NOT used for the DesiredAccess parameter since MapGenericMask must be applied to DesiredAccess before.

It is also not applied to the DACL contained in the SecurityDescriptor as I found out using a C program doing this:

- open the current thread token
- create a security descriptor with owner and default group from the token and an DACL granting GENERIC_ALL to the owner "D:(A;;GA;;;ownerSID)"
- setup GENERIC_MAPPING, which maps (among others) GenericAll to my OWN_READ | OWN_WRITE (defined as 0x0001 and 0x0002)
- call AccessCheck with security descriptor created above, the thread token, OWN_READ as DesiredAccess, the described GENERIC_MAPPING

However, this fails with an access denied error. When I change the security descriptor to "D:(A;;0x0001;;;ownerSID)" access is granted. This shows that AccessCheck is NOT using the GenericMapping parameter to convert generic access flags (GA/GW/GR/GX) in the DACL to the specific access rights. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa374815(v=vs.85).aspx does not give any hints on how the security descriptor should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do almost all correct, but you not take in account that when you try assign security descriptor(`SD`) to kernel object - system not exactly *"as is"* assigned your `SD` but apply `GenericMapping` to `ACEs` first.

every object - have  assosiated [`_OBJECT_TYPE`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/dca/ndk_2obtypes_8h_source.html#l00376) which containing [`_OBJECT_TYPE_INITIALIZER`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d7/dca/ndk_2obtypes_8h_source.html#l00349) and here exist `GENERIC_MAPPING GenericMapping;` and this `GenericMapping` (unique for each type of object) used for convert you generic flags in `ACCESS_MASK` to non-generic.

for test i create file with next `SD` - `"D:P(A;;GA;;;WD)" (10000000 - GenericAll for S-1-1-0 EveryOne)`. and then i query `DACL` from created file - and see really `001F01FF` for `S-1-1-0` but not `10000000`.

when i use `"D:P(A;;GX;;;WD)" (GenericExecute - 20000000 for S-1-1-0)` - in final file i view `001200A0` for `S-1-1-0`

so real kernel object have no generic bits in `ACCESS_MASK` and your `DACL` in exactly form you cannot assign to any object.

> Why is AccessCheck NOT applying GenericMapping to the DACL?

`AccessCheck` assume that `ACCESS_MASK` in `DACL` **already** converted (no generic bits)

*i think this is performance optimization - better convert generic bits once (on object creating or assigning `SD` to it - than every time do this convertation when somebody try open object)*

about how `GenericMapping` parameter used ?

really very weak - only in case when object have no `DACL` (or if `PreviousMode == KernelMode`) and you request `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` as `DesiredAccess` - system grant you `GenericMapping->GenericAll`. this is based on looking source code from `WRK` (`accessck.c`)

no `DACL` and `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` this is rare case, but in this case how system can calculate what concrete access need grant to caller ? he not ask concrete access (like read/write/delete) - but "ALL". so system and give him `GenericMapping->GenericAll`

Comment: That doesn't really explain why the `GenericMapping` parameter exists, if the AccessCheck() function doesn't use it.  Perhaps earlier versions of Windows behaved differently?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - how i write at the end - it used in case `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` requested and object have no DACL (or previous mode is kernel). yes very weak usage. but as is

Comment: no DACL and `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` this is rare case, but in this case how system can calc what concrete access need grant to caller ? he not ask concrete access (like read/write/delete) - but "ALL". so system and give him `GenericMapping->GenericAll`. another usage i not found

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to this! In fact, setting an SD finally results in a call to RtlpSetSecurityObject (base/ntos/rtl/sertl.c) where GenericMapping is applied to DACL and SACL using RtlpApplyAclToObject/RtlMapGenericMask.

However, it did not solve my problem, which I described now in another question. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984950/mapping-of-access-mask-in-dacl-for-cng-keys

Comment: @dannyM - ok, I look this, when be free time. thank for interesting question