# Mapping of access mask in DACL for CNG keys

Tags: winapi, permissions, cng, dacl

(Note: IMO the question is mainly about WinAPI and DACL and not about CNG, so please read on!)

I'm currently trying to modify the sample CNG key storage provider of Microsoft's Cryptographic Provider Development Kit in such a way that it does **not** store the keys in single files. However, I'm in trouble with the security descriptors that can be assigned to the private keys.

In the Certificates Snap-in of the Windows Server Management Console, private keys of certificates can be managed, i.e. the owner, DACL and SACL of a key can be changed, which results in a NCryptSetProperty call with a security descriptor as parameter. For the DACL, the snap-in only allows to allow/deny "full control" or "read", which results in the GENERIC_ALL or GENERIC_READ bit to be set in the access mask of the ACE.

As I have learnt, these generic bits need to be mapped to application specific rights - otherwise AccessCheck will not work. But do I really need to do this by hand???

CreatePrivateObjectSecurity+SetPrivateObjectSecurity does not always work since CreatePrivateObjectSecurity is very picky about the owner and group in the input security descriptor. Moreover, when the mapping is applied, the generic bits are cleared in the access mask, which results in the snap-in showing wrong settings (as I said, the snap-in only considers the GA and GR bits when displaying current permissions).

Seems I'm missing some pieces here...

Answer (score 0):

in your [`CPSetProvParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380276(v=vs.85).aspx) implementation for `PP_KEYSET_SEC_DESCR` you got address of a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`, which you need somehow apply to your private key storage. if your storage based on file(s) or registry key(s) ( in principle any kernel object type, but what more can be used here ?) you need call [`SetKernelObjectSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379578(v=vs.85).aspx) with file or key `HANDLE` (which must have `WRITE_DAC` access) (may be multiple time if you say have multiple files for store single key). in kernel GENERIC access to object will be auto converted to object specific rights.

if your implementation of storage not direct based on some kernel object, but custom - you need yourself at this point convert GENERIC access (`0xF0000000` mask) to specific access rights (`0x0000FFFF` mask)

**__________________ EDIT ____________________**

after more check i found that provider must not only convert generic to specific access in [`CPSetProvParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380276(v=vs.85).aspx) but also convert specific to generic in [`CPGetProvParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380196(v=vs.85).aspx) despite this not directly point in documentation.

this is how [`MS_ENHANCED_PROV`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386986(v=vs.85).aspx) (implemented in `rsaenh.dll`) approximately do this:

```
void CheckAndChangeAccessMask(PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecurityDescriptor)
{
    BOOL bDaclPresent, bDaclDefaulted;
    PACL Dacl;
    ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION asi;

    if (
        GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(SecurityDescriptor, &bDaclPresent, &Dacl, &bDaclDefaulted) 
        &&
        bDaclPresent
        &&
        Dacl
        &&
        GetAclInformation(Dacl, &asi, sizeof(asi), AclSizeInformation)
        &&
        asi.AceCount
        )
    {

        union{
            PVOID pAce;
            PACE_HEADER pah;
            PACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE paa;
        };

        do 
        {
            if (GetAce(Dacl, --asi.AceCount, &pAce))
            {
                switch (pah->AceType)
                {
                case ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE:
                case ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE:
                    ACCESS_MASK Mask = paa->Mask, Gen_Mask = 0;

                    if (Mask & FILE_READ_DATA)
                    {
                        Gen_Mask |= GENERIC_READ;
                    }

                    if (Mask & FILE_WRITE_DATA)
                    {
                        Gen_Mask |= GENERIC_ALL;
                    }

                    paa->Mask = Gen_Mask;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } while (asi.AceCount);
    }
}
```

so `FILE_READ_DATA` converted to `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_WRITE_DATA` to `GENERIC_ALL` (this is exactly algorithm) - however you can look yourself code of `rsaenh.CheckAndChangeAccessMask` (name from pdb symbols)

`rsaenh` first get SD from file by [`GetNamedSecurityInfoW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645(v=vs.85).aspx) (`SE_FILE_OBJECT`) and then convert it specific to generic access.
here the call graph and modified DACL (in the top-right, modified ACCESS_MASK in red color)
[image]

Comment: As I've written above: I'm not applying the received security descriptor to a file or any other kernel object, but need to store it internally. In fact, I try to store all key data (public and private key as well as properties!) in a database. Therefore, only *PrivateObjectSecurity functions would be possible - but do not work (s.a.).

Comment: Mapping GENERIC rights to specific rights **only** is also not right since when CPGetProvParam/NCryptGetPropertyFn should return the SD, I would need to convert it back again. The reason is that the Windows Server Management Console **only** recognizes GENERIC rights. It seems that there is some missing functionality here...

Comment: @dannyM - sorry i was wrong - edit self answer. CP really need convert to generic mask in `CPGetProvParam` - i describe this in edited answer